# Fetch mysql data ignore some value

Tags: mysql

How to get mysql data with ignore some value? The logic :

```
SELECT name,country 
 FROM person 
WHERE name!=jonathan and name!=fedrick and country!=italy
```

Comment: You practically have the query right there. Just fix your quoting issues.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks for quoting examples and in SQL, `<>` is the preferred operator for "not equal to" although `!=` is supported by MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John Conde comment, you just need the quotes. You probably need **quotes** for **string** while **integer** can go **without quotes**.

```
SELECT name,country FROM person WHERE name!='jonathan' and name!='fedrick' and country!='italy'
```

Comment: You have a quote out-of-place, see `name!='fedrick and'`